# Accessing top-level Vue data in nested getter/setter

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vue-devtools

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    {{ foo.bar }}
    <button @click="meaning++">click</button> <!--not reactive-->
    <button @click="foo.bar++">click2</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";

@Component
export default class App extends Vue {
  private meaning = 42;

  private foo = {
    that:this,
    get bar() {
      return this.that.meaning;
    },
    set bar(value) {
      this.that.meaning = value;
    },
  };

  created() {
    console.log(this); // VueComponent {}
    console.log(this.foo.that); // App {}
    console.log(this === this.foo.that); // false
  }
}
</script>
```

I want `foo.bar` to be backed by `meaning` which is a top level data field. I start with the hack above to save `this` (the Vue option instance) in `that`, but I'm also aware that at run time, `this` become the VueComponent instance in component methods, thus `this.meaning` is not `this.foo.that.meaning`.

An extra problem is that the code snippet above will break `vue-devtools` inside Chrome. `vue-devtools` will try invoke `Object.keys()` on `instance._data` which is `null`.

What's the correct way to make `foo.bar` be backed by `meaning`? I might be having arbitrarily complicated logic in those getter and setter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

Since `this` to the VueComponent can only be resolved at runtime, I came to this kinda hackish workaround:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    {{ foo.bar }} 
    <button @click="meaning++">click</button>  <!-- reactive now! -->
    <button @click="foo.bar++">click2</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";

@Component
export default class App extends Vue {
  private meaning = 42;

  private foo = {
    that: {meaning:42} as any, // put exactly the same literal initail value here
    get bar() {
        return this.that.meaning;
    },
    set bar(value) {
      this.that.meaning = value;
    },
  };

  created() {
    this.foo.that = this;
    console.log(this); // VueComponent
    console.log(this.foo.that); // VueComponent
    console.log(this === this.foo.that); // true
  }
}
</script>
```

---

##### Original answer:

For anyone face the same problem, I came to the conclusion that

> it's impossible to refer to outer-level data in inner-level object data in the Vue option instance.

Because the VueComponent instance can only be grabbed at run time, but you have to bind `that:this` in the constructor of the Vue config class, which is prior to the instantiation of VueComponent. Thus the reactive system of Vue won't have any chance to correct the reference in `that`.

So the answer (for me) is simply don't do this. Dependent must always be higher than (or on the equal level of) the dependency, and you can't have `foo` as `bar`'s namespace.

Elevate `bar` to the top level.